# Dynamic Modal Content stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I was told that the dynamic modals on my site are no longer working (causing a lot of errors).
I spent a while trying to debug the code until, gave up and went back to just trying to get the exact code from their guide working (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) .
That is not working either.
http://swtordata.com/modalissues is where it is live.
The modal still pops up but it looks like the script not running. I am guessing there is some config that is wrong with the server or site but I can't figure out what it may be and the javascript error console is not pointing me in the right direction.
This is all of the code in the html.erb for this page:

```
<div class="swtor-ui simple-page">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>
...more buttons...

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
  });
});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume this is not related to the modal itself rather to some error in your site's script saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: changeswtorcartel is not defined" this function is being called in "ajax_showTooltip" function..  You should be looking there for now..

Comment: I have known about that error for a while, until recently it has not broken anything, just an admittedly poorly written javascript.  
The issue here the modal loads but the function in script does not "$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {" ever trigger

Comment: That error has been fixed but the issue described still happens. In chrome no errors in the javascript console.

Comment: Do you mind adding proper syntax to your function such as the smicolons are missing and try wrapping your function in a DOM ready..

Comment: I made those changes and updated the code in the question.